# Placing Value of Array in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am Having one PHP array variable called as

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($PhotoCatIdArray);$i++){
        $msg[$i]=$PhotoCatIdArray[$i];
}
```

The above array having int value like 1,3,5 which i would like to place in mysql SQL query .

```
SELECT * FROM photoCategories WHERE `ID` NOT IN ('1','3','5')
```

I am trying place those array values in the query Not In ('1','3','5') condition. How i can place it , any one have idea to do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($PhotoCatIdArray);$i++){
        $msg[$i]=$PhotoCatIdArray[$i];
}

//for details about implode function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
$str=implode(',',$msg);

$query="SELECT * FROM photoCategories WHERE `ID` NOT IN ($str)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Use implode function:

[PHP implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$msgArr=implode(',',$msg);

$query="SELECT * FROM photoCategories WHERE `ID` NOT IN ($msgArr)";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM photoCategories WHERE `ID` NOT IN (".join(",",$msg).")";
```